# Using a while loop to show an error message if multiple inputs on the same line are not valid?

Tags: java, while-loop

Currently I'm working on a simple algebraic formula calculator to get a little better at some Java basics, but I am running into an issue.

One of my methods is the Quadratic Formula. It asks the user to input A, B, and C on the same line and then the program performs the calculation. But when I make a while loop to check if the input is a double, I get an error when I put in an incorrect value(for example, 3 5 x).

Do I need to perform a loop for each individual variable, or is there a quicker way to check if all 3 variables in one input are acceptable?

```
public static void quadraticFormula() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the values(in order) for A, B and C: ");

    while(!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Error! One or more of your inputs are not acceptable. Please try again: ");
        sc.nextDouble();
    }

    double a = sc.nextDouble();
    double b = sc.nextDouble();
    double c = sc.nextDouble();

    int discriminant = (int) (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c);

    double rootPlus = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    double rootMinus = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

    System.out.println("Your answers are as follows: ");
    System.out.println("\tB + : " + rootPlus);
    System.out.println("\tB - : " + rootMinus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted tries to read 6 values, 3 in the loop and three after that.

I would read in the values as strings and then parse them inside a `try` `catch` block (one for each variable). In that way you can validate that the inputs represent doubles and that you can do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I used a boolean flag and parse for testing double.
Its calculations do not know if they are correct, however the question of the input is right.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Teste {

        public Teste() {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] input = null;
            boolean flag = true;
            double a = 0;
            double b = 0;
            double c = 0;

            while (flag) {
                System.out.print("Please enter the values(in order) for A, B and C: ");
                String str = sc.nextLine();
                input = str.split(" ");
                System.out.println("You entered: " + str);
                if (input.length == 3) {
                    try {
                        a = Double.parseDouble(input[0].trim());
                        b = Double.parseDouble(input[1].trim());
                        c = Double.parseDouble(input[2].trim());
                        flag = false;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        flag = true;
                        System.out.println("Input an integer");
                    }
                } else {
                    flag = true;
                    System.out.print("Please enter the values(in order) for A, B and C: ");
                }
            }
            sc.close();

            int discriminant = (int) (Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c);
            System.out.println(discriminant);
            double rootPlus = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
            double rootMinus = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);

            System.out.println("Your answers are as follows: ");
            System.out.println("\tB + : " + rootPlus);
            System.out.println("\tB - : " + rootMinus);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Teste app = new Teste();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. I've never used try/catch before, so I'll read up on it a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a few thoughts on your issue. I think you can only iterate over a scanner once, so you want to grab the values you want when you get them. While getting the input, you can just check to make sure it's a double. If not, throw a controlled error in a try/catch and just prompt the user again.

You already know that exactly 3 doubles are needed, so creating a list to store your a, b, c might be a good option where index 0 = a, index 1 = b and index 2 = c. I created a method below that might help using this strategy:

```
public static void scannerPractice() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the values(in order) for A, B and C:    
             ");

        //create list to store your a, b, c
        ArrayList<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();

        //iterate over doubles until it has 3 elements (a, b, c)
        while (doubles.size() < 3) {
            //You can use a try to make sure the user is entering doubles
            try {
                doubles.add(sc.nextDouble());
              //found a mismatch, so print error message, enter method to try  
              //try again and break
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Not a double. Please try again: ");
                scannerPractice();
                break;
            }
        }
        //list now has a, b, c
        if (doubles.size() == 3) {
            //iterate over the list to make sure you're getting what's
            //expected
            for (int i = 0; i < doubles.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(doubles.get(i));

            }
            //enter math logic here
        }
        //good practice to close scanner when through
        sc.close();
    }
```